# If $f(\frac{1}{n})=0$ all $ n\to \mathbb{Z^{+}}$ then find $ f'(0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a twice differntiable function and $f(\frac{1}{n})=0$ all $n\in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$? then which of the statement (s) are correct from below.

(a)$f(0)=0$

(b)$f^{'}(0)=0$

(c)$f^{''}(0)=0$

(d)$f$ is a non zero polynomial

I tried of using Tyler series but I wasn't able to do this any help would be appreciated thank

Comment: Differentiable implies continuous. What can you say now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is true via continuity. Second and third options are also true.

One approach is via contradiction. Suppose $f'(0)\neq 0$ then by definition of derivative $f$ is non-zero in a deleted neighborhood of $0$ which sort of contradicts $f(1/n)=0$. Thus $f'(0)=0$.

By mean value theorem $f'(\xi_n) =0$ for some $\xi_n\in(1/(n+1),1/n)$ and hence applying the argument of previous paragraph we have $f''(0)=0$.

The argument can be continued repeatedly to show that $f^{(k)} (0)=0$ provided it exists for all $k\in\mathbb {N} $.

The last option is false. If $f$ were a non-zero polynomial then it could not have an infinite number of roots.